# Check if given integer has only 1s and 0s in it and not another number without loops or functions

Tags: python, binary

> Example:
>
> - `num_1 = 1010`
> - `num_2 = 1234`
> - `num_3 = 1034`
>
> Here `num_1` is the only valid number since it has both 1s and 0s.
>
> `num_2` is invalid because it does not have any 1s or 0s.
>
> `num_3` should also be invalid since it has digits other than 0s and
> 1s which are 2 and 4.
>
> Note: you cannot use any `for` loops or `while` loop or any python
> function or method or string methods or built-in python methods all
> you can use are `if` `elif` and `else`.

All I can use are Conditional statements if, if-else and if-elif-else Simple variable assignment ,Binary operators like and, or and not. I am not supposed to use Any Python method or function. Any Python loop structure. Any list, array, set, or dictionary object.

How can we solve this to find the number which has only 1s and 0s in it?

The given integer can be in between the range 0 and 10000.

Comment: Apparently you are not allowed to use anything so it seems impossible. `if`, `elif` and `else` alone won't do anything useful.

Comment: Well, `set()` is a builtin so I guess you can't use that.

Comment: yea I understand that's the thing I cannot use any methods. All I can use are Conditional statements if, if-else and if-elif-else
,Simple variable assignment
,Binary operators like and, or and not.  I am not supposed to use Any Python method or function. 
Any Python loop structure.
Any list, array, set, or dictionary object.

Comment: As mentioned, conditionals have no logical operators to actually do checks. You **need** some functions or methods.

Comment: well the range of the numbers are from 0 to 10000. and I have to accept only numbers in binary form and reject numbers like 102 from input.

Comment: well then you can do five `n, r = n//10, n % 10; if r > 1: return False` statements. Why not list all the rules in your question in the first place?

Comment: *"all you can use are if elif and else"* - That doesn't even allow a syntactically valid program other than the empty one.

Comment: *"Binary operators like and, or and not"* - `not` is not a binary operator but a unary one.

Comment: Please do not vandalize or deface your question. This is not allowed per site rules that you agreed to on joining, and also it creates unnecessary extra work for those of us who help curate the site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not sure if you accidentally rolled back twice, but that raised an automatic "rollback war" flag, which was helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Given the significant set of restrictions:

```
if num == 0: return True
elif num == 1: return True
elif num == 10: return True
elif num == 11: return True
elif num == 100: return True
elif num == 101: return True
elif num == 110: return True
elif num == 111: return True
elif num == 1000: return True
elif num == 1001: return True
elif num == 1010: return True
elif num == 1011: return True
elif num == 1100: return True
elif num == 1101: return True
elif num == 1110: return True
elif num == 1111: return True
elif num == 10000: return True
else: return False
```

Comment: Isn't `==` a "bulit in method"? `__eq__`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Ah damn. Good point.

Comment: yea what if we are allowd to use built-in methods can we solve it then.?

Comment: How can anything be evaluated by `if` if the dunders are off limits? The requirements are ill-defined and/or absurd.

Comment: but even though the answer suggested by bill even if we use == i would have to hardcode for numbers from 0 to 10000.

Comment: yeaa well thats what I was supposed to solve. and I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Well, since it's only up to 10000, there's only 16 possible valid numbers.

Comment: Simplify ... `return num in {1, 10, 11, ...}`

Comment: Bill's answer is not a joke, it is correct for integers less than 5 digits.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: No. It's a joke. But so is the question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sets are probably not allowed.

Comment: sets are not allowed

Comment: You forgot 101 and 1101.

Comment: @vamsikintali Your question never says any data-structures are not allowed.

Comment: Sorry missed it I made the changes

Comment: yo thank you all for answering I am gonna go ahead and close this question and end the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Because the number has a range, you can inline the while loop:

```
def only_one_or_zero(num):
    if num == 0: return True
    last = num % 10
    if last != 0 and last != 1: return False
    num //= 10
    if num == 0: return True
    last = num % 10
    if last != 0 and last != 1: return False
    num //= 10
    if num == 0: return True
    last = num % 10
    if last != 0 and last != 1: return False
    num //= 10
    if num == 0: return True
    last = num % 10
    if last != 0 and last != 1: return False
    num //= 10
    if num == 0: return True
    last = num % 10
    return last == 0 or last == 1
```

Test:

```
>>> all(only_one_or_zero(i) == ({'0', '1'} >= set(str(i))) for i in range(100001))
True
```